# Passing an address of a object using the pointer of the same type

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

In `MainWindow::runButton_clicked()` I have instantiated an object of type `GraphWindow`. I need to access this object by another function in `MainWindow`, so I tried passing the address of the object to a pointer of same type;

In MainWindow.h

```
//Forward declaring Graphwindow
class GraphWindow;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
     //Member slots

     GraphWindow *graphPtr;
}

in MainWindow.cpp

MainWindow::on_runButton_clicked()
{
      GraphWindow graphObj;
      MainWindow::graphPtr = &graphObj;         

      //Other code
}

MainWindow::someFunction()
{
      MainWindow::graphPtr->exec();
}
```

I know this is not the most elegant way to do things; The reason why I am doing this;

- I can't create a object of `GraphWindow` in `MainWindow` definition
  since `class GraphWindow` is forward declared there
- I could just use the pointer 'GraphPtr`to access all its member functions in`MainWindow::on_runButton_clicked()`but I'm using this function called`QTimer::singleShot()`in`MainWindow::on_runButton_clicked()`which requires a object of type`GraphWindow`

Anyway I guess the way I doing by storing the address of the object created in a pointer ad accessing the later is correct. But not sure why my program crashes. Any advice appreciated. 
.

Comment: As it is created on the stack, graphObj is destroyed at the end of on_runButtonClicked()

Comment: a pointer won't keep an object alive once it's gone out of scope. at the end of `on_runButton_clicked()` `graphObj` is destroyed. `graphPtr` is now a dangling pointer.
It seems to me that you will need to allocate graphObj dynamically in on_runBittonClicked and then delete it once you've used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the address of a local variable on the stack. When the `on_runButton_clicked` function returns, that `GraphWindow` object is destructed/deallocated. This is called a *dangling pointer*: any code that accesses that pointer later invokes undefined behavior.

One solution: allocate the object on the heap with `new` (and don't forget to `delete` it!):

```
MainWindow::on_runButton_clicked()
{
      GraphWindow* graphObj = new GraphWindow();
      MainWindow::graphPtr = graphObj;         

      // Other code
}

// whenever you're done with graphPtr:
delete MainWindow::graphPtr;
```